# Perform a Vlookup in Excel for multiple lines of data with the same lookup value (primary key)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to do a Vlookup for Names that have multiple lines for the same primary key:

```
Deal ID (Primary Key) | Name
437                   | Tom Jones
437                   | Frank Thomas
437                   | Mary Smith
```

The Vlookup will only return the 1st Name in the record (Tom Jones). What I would like it to do look like is this: Tom Jones, Frank Thomas, Mary Smith all in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Excel as a relational database, which it isn't all that great at. To top it all off, unless there's been a change in recent years (I have not had the pleasure of using anything later than Excel 2010), there is no worksheet function to turn a range or array into a delimited string. You'll have to come up with a VBA worksheet function that does that.

You can use a combination of array formula and VBA to do what you want. Before you go further, I would strongly suggest that you use a real database program if you find yourself doing things like this on a regular basis. I have abused Excel into doing simple relational-database-like tasks in the past, but only simple ones. If I had to do anything more complex, it would have been extremely painful.

Assuming your ID to search for is in cell `F1` and your table is called `Table1`, you enter the following as an ***array formula*** (use control-shift-enter, instead of enter). `SimpleCat` is your VBA concatenation worksheet function.

```
=SimpleCat(IF(Table1[Deal ID (Primary Key)]=$F$1, Table1[Name], ""))
```

A `SimpleCat` that will work for this particular instance is the following:

```
Function SimpleCat(Args() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim a As Variant
    SimpleCat = ""
    For Each a In Args
        If a <> "" Then SimpleCat = SimpleCat & a & ", "
    Next
    If Len(SimpleCat) > 0 Then SimpleCat = Left$(SimpleCat, Len(SimpleCat) - 2)
End Function
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to expand on `SimpleCat` to make it more general, since having a more full-featured generic concatenation function is useful in anyone's toolbox.

Explanation:

When evaluated as an array formula, comparing an entire table column to a single value will produce an array of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s. Using an `IF` will construct a new array, pulling values from the correct position of the array you're using on the value if true side of the `IF`, and filling in the empty string you're using on the value if false side of the `IF`. The `SimpleCat` function puts all the non-empty values in this new array together with commas between them.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. First, that's not a primary key; second, there's no built-in functionality in Excel that's going to give you the result you're after.

A Primary Key should be a unique identifier that is tied to a single record, and that never, ever repeats. That's what most of the Lookup functions in Excel are designed to work with, which is why they stop when they find a match - it saves resources not to have to look through the entire range every time if a match has already been found.

The only way I could see to do the kind of consolidation you're looking for here, pulling multiple values into a single string, would be to use a macro or a custom function. Exactly what code you need would depend on the exact result you're after, and is outside the scope of this answer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I would take this function...

```
Function ConcatRange(inputRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String) As String
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim usedRange As Range

    Set usedRange = Application.Intersect(inputRange.Parent.usedRange, inputRange.Cells)
    If Not (usedRange Is Nothing) Then
        For Each oneCell In usedRange
            If oneCell.Text <> vbNullString Then
                ConcatRange = ConcatRange & delimiter & Trim(oneCell.Text)
            End If
        Next oneCell
        ConcatRange = Mid(ConcatRange, Len(delimiter) + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

and modify it to make a new function that would be something like:

```
Function ConcatIf(KeyRange as Range, KeyValue as Variant, DataColumnOffset As Integer)
```

where it would loop through each cell within KeyRange and, only if its value equaled KeyValue, concatenate the value from `oneCell.Offset(0, DataColumnOffset)`